# What happened to Megatron's spark?

Tags: transformers, beast-wars

I just finished watching Transformers: Beast Wars and one thing bothered me.  To gain more power Predacon Megatron steals the spark from Decepticon Megatron and merges them together, but when Rhinox destroys the Nemesis and hits Megatron with the shuttle and he sticks to it like a bug on a windshield. In the next scene you see all of the Maximals in that ship flying back to Cybertron with Megatron still stuck to the outside of the ship.

Did the Decepticon Megatron ever get his spark back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a deleted scene, Optimus Primal rips the spark from Predacon Megatron and re-inserts it into Decepticon-Megatron's body.